# How to style angular ngBind currency

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to make that with angularjs and css:
[image]

Basically, the decimal part of the number should be in the upper right corner as you see in the image. I know that, with ng-bind we can make it normally aligned. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value Initialization (from controller)

```
$scope.model.currency = 10.20;
```

Directive Call

```
<div gl-currency="model.currency"></div>
```

Directive JS

```
.directive('glCurrency', [function()
{
  return {
    scope: 
    {
      glCurrency: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'currency.html',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs)
    {
      $scope.$watch('glCurrency', function(currency)
      {
        if(currency)
        {
          var split = currency.toString().split('.');

          if(Array.isArray(split))
          {
            $scope.number.dollars = split[0] ? split[0] : '0';
            $scope.number.cents = split[1] ? split[1] : '00';
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Directive Template

```
<div class="currency">
  <span class="currency__dollars">{{ number.dollars }}</span>
  <span class="currency__cents">{{ number.cents }}</span>
</div>
```

Directive Styling

```
.currency {
  position: relative;
}

.currency__dollars {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-right: 10px; 
}

.currency__cents {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. How would I do that, but instead of passing the value 10.20, using a ng-bind for two way data-binding?

Comment: @wagnerdelima Good question, edited for 2 way binding!

Comment: @wagnerdelima Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done if you separate the 2 parts. For example with a directive:

```
.directive("separatedCurrency", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            amount: "=",
            symbol: "@",
            fraction: "="
        },
        template: "<span class='currency-main' ng-bind='amount | currency:symbol:0'></span><span class='currency-decimals' ng-bind='decimals'></span>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.fraction = scope.fraction || 2; // default 2 decimals
            scope.decimals = (scope.amount % 1) * (10^scope.fraction);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can style the `currency-main` and `currency-decimals` separately with css.

Comment: I haven't tested it, I was just trying to give you an example